# Protractor more than one element found for locator By(css selector, .image-holder) - the first result will be used

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests

How would I be able to reference by index? I am trying to write automated tests to test an Angular 6 website.

```
element.all(by.css(".image-holder")).click();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry managed to solve the problem

Here's the code for future reference:

```
element.all(by.css(".image-holder")).get(0).click();
```

Comment: You can also use `element.all(by.css(".image-holder")).first().click();` if you always want the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try identifying the tags by id

```
 const div = element.querySelectorAll('div')[0];
```